# Would Farming Simulator 15 run on my laptop?

Tags: farming-simulator-2015

Will my following laptop run Farming Simulator 15 ?

LENOVO IdeaPad 110 15.6" Laptop

- Intel® Celeron® N3060 Processor
- Dual-core
- 1.6 GHz / 2.48 GHz (Burst)
- 2 MB cache
- Memory (RAM) : 4 GB DDR3 (8 GB maximum installable RAM)
- Storage : 1 TB HDD, 5400 rpm

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -2):

For playing *Farming Simulator 2015* you will need:

- CPU: 2.0 GHz CPU,
- RAM: 2 GB Ram
- GPU: Video Card with 512 MB or higher (NVIDIA 8600 / RADEON 2600)

For example look [here on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hO-5sEXZRPk). This guy has better configuration and he set graphic to low details and he had 25-35 fps.
Or look [here on this "second guy"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9kWyXE6_xnk). This "second" guy has (or had) worse CPU than you, but game was playable (by YouTube video).
I can not guarantee that this game will run at 100% at your laptop, but propably yes.